# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What in the Wide, Wide World of Sports is Going On Here?

TL;DR -- put images and links in the answers. If they get voted up enough, they will appear on the main site as community promotion ads.

#### But whyyyyyyy?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting Android apps
- the site's twitter account
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. And to click on it for great justice!

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/748).

Comment: Hmm...I think we should advertise our chat channel. (It's too late to advertise the election.)

Comment: "interesting Android apps," is there any restriction to this if you are the developer of said app? I understand the community will still have to upvote it enough to have it shown, but just wanting to clarify

Comment: @AlEverett Feel free! It may be a good way to get more participation and perhaps a more lively attendance. Just be sure to be there so people who do drop by from the ad aren't visiting a ghost town. ♪

Comment: @Bryan No restriction, you are free to push your wares if people are fine with it. You might find it appropriate to note in a comment that you are the creator of the app, of course. The real main restrictions come from being on Meta (which thus restricts this to real participants of the community, rather than any ol' agendapusher) and of course the need for community approval by votes.

Comment: I think we need a new one. I'll get to it :)

Comment: @Liam I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]